# Go executable coverage

Tags: go

It is possible to obtain coverage information when running a test in Go by using `go test -cover ...`, but this coverage doesn't extend to main programs which are invoked by the test. Is there some way of building a Go executable so that it is instrumented for coverage?

Comment: The cover tool can do this. See `$ go tool cover -h`

Comment: It's a bit tedious though. you have to generate an annotated coverage source code, and then create a testing coverage report manually. It's simpler to just run the program with a special test that runs main()